# MKMapView and setRegion:animated: not updating the map visuals

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, android-mapview

Greetings! I'm attempting to use **MKMapView** without any Apple code samples, though there are a few others out there of varying clarity. (I know, "Read the friendly manual." I've done that but it's not 100% clear, so please bear with me on this one.)

Here's the situation. I have a **MKMapView** object, wherein I have added a set of about ten **MKPinAnnotation** objects. So far, so good. Everything is alloced/released sanely and there doesn't appear to be any complaints from Instruments.

Upon initial display, I set up a **MKCoordinateRegion** object with the centerpoint at our first pin location, and a (arbitrary) span of 0.2 x 0.2. I then call:

```
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Wow! That worked well.

Meanwhile ... I also have a segmented control to allow for movement to each pin location. So as I tap through the list, the map animates to each new pin location with a new pair of calls to **setRegion:animated:** and **regionThatFits:** ... or at least that's the idea.

While the map does "travel" to the new pin location, the map itself doesn't update underneath. Instead, I see my pin on a gray/blank-map background ... *until* I nudge the map in any direction, however slightly. Then the map shows through! (If I'm only moving within a short distance of the previous pin location, I'll usually see whatever part of the map was already loaded.)

I suspect I'm doing something dumb here, but I haven't been able to figure out what, at least not from the MapKit docs. Perhaps I'm using the wrong calls? (Well, I do need to set the region at least once, yes? Moving that around doesn't seem to help though.) I have also tried using **setCenterCoordinate:animated:** - same problem.

I'm assuming nothing at this point (no pun intended). Just trying to find my way.

Clues welcome/appreciated!

UPDATE: Calling **setRegion:animated:** and **regionThatFits:** the first time, followed by **setCenterCoordinate:animated:** while traversing the list, has no effect. Interesting finding though: If I change animated to NO in both cases, the map updates!!! Only when it's set to YES. (Wha happen?! Is animated: broken? That can't be ... ???)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the map update doesn't work when using the SIMULATOR. When I try **setCenterCoordinate:animated:** on the device, I *do* get the map update underneath.

Bottom line: I was trusting the simulator to match the device in terms of map updating behavior. Alas, I was mistaken! Lesson learned. "Don't let this happen to you." :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke the `setRegion:animated:` call in the Main thread context.
Just do something like:

```
....
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateMyMap) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

}

-(void) updateMyMap {
    [myMap setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];    
}
```

and it should work in any case (animated or not), with the map updated underneath.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this, and ... it works. However, I then discovered that it works without making this call too. So what changed? Well, it turns out that the map update doesn't work when using the SIMULATOR. When I try it on the device, I get the map update underneath. So I was trusting the simulator to match the device in terms of something like map updating behavior. Alas, I was mistaken! Lesson learned.

Comment: Have similar problem on 3.1. This approach doesn't help me. My topic is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190270/mkmapview-refresh-after-pin-moves

Answer (score 0):

Hum strange. The map updates on my Mac even in the simulator. Maybe a network setting (proxy or whatever) that would prevent the map widget to download the tiles on the simulator ?

Comment: Strange indeed! I'm not sure what I would set, network-wise, because all it takes is a little nudge moving the map and - ta-dah - there it is. I'd say "I'm using the 3.0 environment" but then I just realized MKMapView is only available starting with 3.0b, so that can't be it. :\

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old topic I thought I'd ring in with my experience. It seems the map animation only fails on devices running iOS 3.1.x and the simulator running 3.1.x. My dev iPod touch with 3.1.3 fails to zoom if animation is on.