# MapKit (iOS) -- Live MKAnnotation Motion

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm designing an app using Swift for a food truck. I want to use MapKit to show a pin on the live location of the truck so one can look at the app to see it moving in realtime. I was able to get the server-side element set up using PHP/MySQL. Currently, the app makes a HTTP request every 3 seconds.

How should I go about animating the moving pin (or other image)? I tried a few methods already (if you have others, please suggest!):

1. I removed the pin and quickly added a new one in my HTTP function. While this works, I would prefer a smooth animation, not a flashing, jerky pin.
2. I subclassed `MKMapViewDelgate` like with a `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate that animates the pin's frame using `UIView.animateWithDuration` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655465/custom-pin-animation-mkmapview). Animation only occurred when the map was initially loaded. Also, I have no idea how this would work with coordinates, since it involves frames.
3. I subclassed `MKAnnotation` with a modifiable `var coordinate`. In my HTTP function, I changed the coordinate. **EDIT**: This now works since I [properly refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1205230/4967340) the mapView (thanks @Paulw11). However, I still have two main issues:

   - There's no linear animation, which I desire to better simulate real-time movement. How would I go about animating the pin's coordinates? Should I use UIView, like in method 2, a fast NSTimer, or something else?
   - Due to using the `setCenterCoordinate` function to forcibly refresh the map, the map cancels any current touches. How do I detect if there's any touches on the MapView so I can prevent the forced update?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256177/how-to-move-a-mkannotation-without-adding-removing-it-from-the-map/5300600#5300600

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks, but I have already tried that (method 1).

Comment: Did you call `viewForAnnotation` after changing the coordinate?  There were a couple of other options listed as answers on that question too

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks! it's working now, but it still isn't a smooth animation like I wanted.

Comment: Unfortunately if you want smooth animations then I think you will need to interpolate the positions between the start and end locations and animate the intermediate locations

Comment: have you solved it now. I am working on same thing.

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz I did, but it was a fairly "hacky" approach of removing and re-creating the pin many times per second. Ended up migrating to Google Maps API.